# Push asterisk data to X-lite Softphones

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I have an asterisk server up and running on a ubuntu machine for my personal project. I can receive calls in mac and make calls with my X-lite softphone on my agent's MacOS. The call center has an IVR with only two options-  support, and sales.

Now I want an IVR where we will ask if the customer has an invoice id, if he doesn't have an invoice id, we will connect him to the sales queue. If he has an invoice id, we tell him to press the invoice id followed by #, then we will connect the user to the support queue.

So, I want to send the invoice number to the agent somehow, we want to know if asterisk can push it to the X-lite where it shows the phone number (Incoming call).

Now it shows something like this:

```
Incoming Call:
01234567891
```

Suppose the user of this number has pressed 56666 as invoice number, followed by a #.

We want the notification to be like:

```
Incoming Call:
01234567891 56666
```

We have come to know that for such cases using AMI to push the data is the best practice. But we can't figure if it is internally possible to change the push notification format on the X-lite softphone without the AMI.

If it's not possible, the next steps would be to build a web UI, where shopper phone no and invoice ID will be shown. It will be taking the data from the localhost AMI NodeJS client. But it will be a hassle for the agents to switch the context between softphone and web browser.

Answer (score 1):

1) ask customer invoice id - use IVR in dialplan, described in any book.

2) write customer invoice_id for agent - use

```
Set(CALLERID(name)=${invoice_id})
```